# Group element in a list to create dictionary based on digits as keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list like:

```
list = ['1', 'call-appr', '5', 'call-pickup', '2', 'call-appr', '6', 'call-park', '3', 'call-appr', '7', 'empty', '4', 'team', 'E', '123-456-212', 'R.']
```

I want to group them to get a dictionary of following format:

```
dict1 = {
    '1': 'call-appr', 
    '2': 'call-appr',
    '3':'call-appr', 
    '4': ['team','E','123-456-212','R'],
    '5':'call-pickkup',
    '6':'call-park',
    '7':'empty'
}
```

Here's the code I tried:

```
for value in list:
    if value.isdigit():
        index = list.index(value)
        list_index_num.append(index)
print (list_index_num)

for value in range(len(list_index_num)):
    if value != len(list_index_num)-1:
        number = range(list_index_num[value]+1, list_index_num[value+1])

    else:
        number = range(list_index_num[value]+1, len(list))


    for i in number:

        dct = {list[list_index_num[value]]:list[i]}

    print (number)
```

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: I am so sorry, I forgot put my scripts..

Comment: Side-note: Don't name variables `list`; nameshadowing built-ins is going to cause you no end of grief over time. You seemed to notice this when you used `dct` instead of `dict`; `lst` instead of `list` is a similarly good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) and [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) with *dictionary comprehension* to achieve this as:

```
from itertools import takewhile
my_list = ['1', 'call-appr', '5', 'call-pickup', '2', 'call-appr', '6', 'call-park', '3', 'call-appr', '7', 'empty', '4', 'team', 'E', '123-456-212', 'R.']

my_dict = {s: list(takewhile(lambda x: not x.isdigit(), my_list[i+1:]))  for i, s in enumerate(my_list) if s.isdigit()}
```

where `my_dict` will have:

```
{'1': ['call-appr'], '5': ['call-pickup'], '2': ['call-appr'], '6': ['call-park'], '3': ['call-appr'], '7': ['empty'], '4': ['team', 'E', '123-456-212', 'R.']}
```

Here I am using [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) as a filter to identify whether the string is a digit or not.

Note that here you are getting even single value items as list instead of string in your dictionary, which you can remove by doing explicit iteration on dictionary.

If you are on Python version 3.8+, you can remove it within *dictionary comprehension* by using [*Walrus Operator*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) `:=` as:

```
my_dict = {s: l if len(l:=list(takewhile(lambda x: not x.isdigit(), my_list[i+1:]))) > 1 else l[0] for i, s in enumerate(my_list) if s.isdigit()}
```

which will return you the dictionary in your desired format:

```
{
    '1': 'call-appr', 
    '5': 'call-pickup', 
    '2': 'call-appr', 
    '6': 'call-park', 
    '3': 'call-appr', 
    '7': 'empty', 
    '4': ['team', 'E', '123-456-212', 'R.']
}
```

Comment: it's cool. Thank you very much, anyway it's so confused when write code in one line ^_^

Comment: ^_^ I also used `str.isdigit()` but It's no really useful like you

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in a loop that avoids going through the list twice:

```
data = ['1', 'call-appr', '5', 'call-pickup', '2', 'call-appr', 
        '6', 'call-park', '3', 'call-appr', '7', 'empty', 
        '4', 'team', 'E', '123-456-212', 'R.']

dict1 = dict()
for v in data:
    if v.isdigit(): dict1[v] = group = []
    else:           group.append(v)
        
print(dict1)
{'1': ['call-appr'], '5': ['call-pickup'], '2': ['call-appr'], 
 '6': ['call-park'], '3': ['call-appr'], '7': ['empty'], 
 '4': ['team', 'E', '123-456-212', 'R.']}
```

I would not recommend using a data structure where the type of value changes depending on the number of occurrences. This will make all the code using it more complex as it will constantly need to perform type checking.

If you need to do that however, you could modify the loop like this

```
dict1 = dict()
for v in data:
    if v.isdigit():      k = v
    elif k not in dict1: dict1[k],group   = v,[v]
    else:                dict1[k] = group = group+[v]
        
print(dict1)
{'1': 'call-appr', '5': 'call-pickup', '2': 'call-appr', 
 '6': 'call-park', '3': 'call-appr', '7': 'empty', 
 '4': ['team', 'E', '123-456-212', 'R.']}
```

Comment: Could you explain me the `dict1[v] = group = []` How did they work?

Comment: This assigns an empty list to both the `dict1` dictionary at key `v` and the variable `group`.  From that point on, the `group` variable and the `dict1[v]` item point to the same list.  So, when I append a value to `group` later on, i'm actually adding it to the last `dict1[v]` item as well.  This way I don't have to find the key again in `dict1` on subsequent items of the list

Comment: How intelligent you are!

Answer (score 1):

```
dict1 ={}
for element in list1:
    if element.isdigit():
        current_key = element
        dict1[current_key] = []
    else:
        dict1[current_key].append(element)

# this part only flattens one-element lists
for key in list(dict1.keys()):
    if len(dict1[key]) == 1:
        dict1[key] = dict1[key][0]
```

I came up with something like this, it appears to do exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work:

```
dict={}
for i in range(0,len(my_list),2):
    dict[my_list[i]]=my_list[i+1]
```

(note I changed your identifier `list` to `my_list`)

Comment: It wouldnt work with '4' that has 4 element behinds